# How to create menu on windows OS to pin application to taskbar with JavaFX?

Tags: windows, javafx

Is it possible to create menu on right click (Java 8) to be able to pin application to taskbar windows?

I have been searching over the net and found a new class in Java 9 - `TaskBar`, but I do not have that Java version.

Comment: You are not supposed to programmatically pin shortcuts! Only the user should do that.

Comment: Yeah, i get that, but i do not know how to get context menu to add menu item to it which says "pint this app to...". If i right click over icon in taskbar over the running app - i have only menu item which says "close the app". Do you know how to programatically get the context menu? Thank you!